# PHP SessionHandler->write says no array or string given, but string is given

Tags: php, session

I am running PHP 7.4.26 (cli) (built: Nov 22 2021 09:47:55) ( NTS ) and I am using an instance of the base PHP \SessionHandler class.

When calling

```
$sessionHandler->write($id, $data);
```

I get an error message as follows:

**PHP Warning: Invalid callback , no array or string given in /var/www/source/typo3conf/ext/my_authentication/Classes/Service/SessionHandler.php line 43**

With

```
$id = 'myAuthenticationData';
$data = 'a:1:{s:15:"someSession";s:26:"fb88d1daf0ffaff15d34a6c961";}';
```

What do I have to change to be able to write into the session? I am clearly providing two strings to the write method of this base class.

```
37:     $object = [
38:         'someSession' => 'fb88d1daf0ffaff15d34a6c961';
39:     ];
40:     $this->sessionHandler = new \SessionHandler();
41:     $this->sessionHandler->open('authentication', 'user');
42:     $sessionData = serialize($object);
43:     $this->sessionHandler->write('myAuthenticationData', $sessionData);
```

Comment: From the error it doesn't seem to use the PHP's SessionHandler but instead some class from the given path typo3conf/ext...

Comment: what is the script on /var/www/source/typo3conf/ext/my_authentication/Classes/Service/SessionHandler.php line 43 ?

Comment: First, you haven't shown us your actual code, just tiny snippets that may not even indicate where the actual problem lies. We need a proper sample of your code in order to analyze the problem properly. Second, why are you invoking the `SessionHandler::write()` method directly? That just screams bad practice to me. Why not make use of `session_write_close()` to commit any changes to the `$_SESSION` superglobal? This would likely save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: @RoyalBg: I added the relevant lines of code in the first post. This should be PHP's SessionHandler.

Comment: @HeryKurniawan: See above.